# Why cancleButton of UIActionSheet becomes the first button on iOS7 device

Tags: swift, ios7, uiactionsheet

I ran my app on iPhone5s iOS7. The indexes of buttons are wrong, cancleButton  becomes the first button. I am confused that when I tap the background, it opens the album. I don't know why. So strange.

[图片在这里](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9iJ5.png)

This is my code.

```
func actionsheetInIOS8Early() {

    let actionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: nil, delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "cancle", destructiveButtonTitle: nil)

    actionSheet.addButtonWithTitle("album")

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable( UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) {

        actionSheet.addButtonWithTitle("camera")

    }

    actionSheet.showInView(self.view)

}
```

Comment: That's because in the Buttons array of action sheet, the first element is Cancel button. Other buttons are added after it. So when it loads, cancel button is on the top as it is on index 0.

Answer (score 0):

When you add

```
let actionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: nil, delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "cancle", destructiveButtonTitle: nil)
```

this line  it will add Cancel button to index 0 and then after it will add your buttons

```
actionSheet.addButtonWithTitle("album")

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable( UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) {

        actionSheet.addButtonWithTitle("camera")

    }
```

Album button at index 1 & Camera at index 2

So If you want Cancel button at last index then you need to add  like

```
    actionSheet.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel")
```

after adding your button for Album and Camera.

Comment: If so, cancelButton indeed is the third button, but three of them close together, cancleButton should be separate from the first two button and cancleButton is at bottom

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet);

if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable( UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera){
    let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .Default, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            // do something 
        })
    optionMenu.addAction(cameraAction);
}

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        print("Cancelled")
    })
optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction);

self.presentViewController(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

If u add cancel button as above, cancel button will shown at the end of the AlertController

Comment: if u write some code between second line and third line, u can do something when cancel button is clicked

Comment: This code is used for adaptation iOS7

Comment: :( if it doesn't work, tell me that i can figure out what's wrong with this code

Comment: Your code is fine on iOS8 and later, but can't use on iOS7

Comment: It's very kind of u. I find the answer